# Change color of background if function returns number between 0 and 6

Tags: php, html, css

I've got a PHP function displayed on a website:

```
<div class="metacontent"><div><span> <?php the_field('metascore'); ?> </span></div> </div>
```

This returns the metascore of a movie, defined by a plugin in wordpress where authors can just type the score as they edit a post.

I now want to style the results with different background colors, depending on what score the movie gets:

```
.metacontentG {
    position: relative;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: #6c3;
}

.metacontentY {
    position: relative;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: #fc3;
}

.metacontentR {
    position: relative;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

In other words, I want to use .metacontentG if the score is above 6 (the function the_field('metascore') returns a value above 6). I want to use .metacontentY if the score is between 4 and 6. I want to use .metacontentR if the score is below 4.

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make an if statement to determine which category it falls into:

```
$score = get_field('metascore'); 

if($score < 4) {    
  $class = "R";
} elseif($score < 6) {
  $class = "Y";
} else {
  $class = "G";
}
```

Then echo it like this:

```
<div class="metacontent<?php echo $class; ?>"><div><span> <?php echo $score; ?> </span></div> </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for, I'm just not good enough yet to write it myself, but I can understand what it's doing. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will match scores 1-3 as R, 4-5 as Y and 6+ as G. If you want 4 to be included in the R category you will need to use <= instead of <, same goes for 6.

Comment: Thanks! One quick question if you don't mind; why is it get_field instead of the_field? You edited your first answer and it only worked after I used the edited version.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin (or a plugin that uses it) in that case the function `the_field('field')` is equivalent to `echo(get_field('field'));` - meaning `the_field()` does not return the value it just echos the value returned by `get_field()`

Answer (score 0):

Update to your function `the_field` to return `array(score => 6, class =>metacontentR)` or something similar and then in your html you can use the string as a class

```
<div class="<?php the_field('metascore')['class'] ?>"><div><span> <?php the_field('metascore')['score']; ?> </span></div> </div>
```

Comment: So I'd have to find the function in the plugins folder and edit it there somehow? Or find a way to do it with a child theme?

I can't just hack it in the html file?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use As:-

```
<?php
$response = the_field('metascore')
?>
<div class="<?php if($response==1) { echo "metacontentG"; } if($response==2) { echo "metacontentC"; } ?>"><div><span> <?php the_field('metascore'); ?> </span></div>
```

You can also try with switch case

Comment: Keep in mind the_field() will likely echo the value out and not return the value (going by the op's original code) - get_field() is probably the correct function to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mscore = get_field('metascore'); 
$className = "G";
if($mscore !="")
{
    if($mscore > 4 && $mscore < 6) {    
        $className = "Y";
    } elseif($mscore > 6) {
        $className = "G";
    } elseif($mscore < 4) {
        $className= "R";
    }
}

<div class="<?php print $className;?>" ><div><span> <?php the_field('metascore'); ?> </span></div> </div>
```